# How to automatically remove all meta data from file(s) using Linux OS?

Tags: security, privacy, metadata, tags, privacy-protection

On daily basis dozen of files arrive at my virtual desktop and they find their way to their next destination on:

- Cloud
- mailbox
- shared_folders
- mobile_devices
- etc

I have noticed that some of them tend to carry auxilary info with them as
metadata, tags etc, this is concerning since some may transmit more information about the authors or the channel traveled then intended.

Is there one integrated tool or a set of them that can be streamlined through coding/scripting etc to remove almost everything but the main content from files?

I am playing around with ExifTool however it does not seem to be the best candidate yet.